# Как убрать крестик на input в IE 9 и IE 10?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, internet-explorer, input

По-умолчанию  Internet Explorer 9 и 10 при фокусе на `input` (`type="text"`, `type="email"`, `type="url"`, `type="number"`, `type="tel"`, `type="search"`) появляется крестик очистки содержимого поля.

Как убрать эту кнопку с `input` в IE 9 и IE 10?

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko не вижу решения в вашем "дубликате" для input с type="password"

Comment: Перед тем, как задавать вопрос, мне кажется правильным поискать существующий вопрос. Учитывая, что ответили вы сами на свой же вопрос, то кусочек кода с `::-ms-reveal` можно добавить как ответ на существующий вопрос. Ну и про `type=password` вы дописали уже после моего комментария :-)

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko ответ на  type=password был до вашего комментария) Будьте внимательней) Я просто исправил описание после вашего комментария. Тем более, мой ответ гораздо расширинней и предлагает несколько вариантов решения.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko есть даже решение для IE 9.

Comment: Речь о дубликате вопроса, а не о качестве ответа. Перед тем, как задавать вопрос, пользуйтесь поиском — изначально ваш вопрос был полной копией уже имеющегося.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko изначально не видел. Но теперь, когда увидел, доработал и сделал гораздо лучше и вопрос и ответ. Да и в поиске гугла вопрос будет найти легче.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Убрать этот крестик в IE 10 можно так:

```
::-ms-clear {
    display: none;
}
```

Или же так:

```
::-ms-clear {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

Для поля type="password" значок можно убрать с помощью селектора `::-ms-reveal`:

```
::-ms-reveal {
    display: none;
}
```

Вот только в Internet Explorer 9 эти значки будут портить всю верстку, так как IE 9 не поддерживает `::-ms-clear` и `::-ms-reveal`. Для решения этой проблемы можно абсолютно спозиционировать блок с белым фоном, которое «перекроет» лишние знаки в ваших input'ах.